# Mongo Database Profiler: What is this query?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to understand this line of output from the Mongo Database Profiler:

```
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-10T20:58:16.805Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "streamified.system.indexes", "query" : { "ns" : "streamified.cache_b7dd924a2dab81cc0d47346982d90ee1s" }, "nscanned" : 34566, "nreturned" : 2, "responseLength" : 304, "millis" : 130, "client" : "10.188.17.26", "user" : "" }
```

Obviously, it is something to do with the indexes on my cache_b7dd924a2dab81cc0d47346982d90ee1s collection. However, I am unclear what is happening here, since usually I see the query which is being performed within the query object, not just the ns. The fact that the ns is the system.indexes seems to imply that the indexes on my  table are being either queried or updated.

The reason I ask is that I have many queries in the profiler of this nature, and they are my slowest queries, so I'm trying to optimize them... but I don't know where they're coming from ;)

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  Is this part of a replica set?  Are you using sharding?

Comment: Also: this result indicates that you have 34,566 indexes in the 'streamified' database -- is that correct?

Comment: Mongo reports "db version v2.0.2, pdfile version 4.5". I'm guessing that the # of indexes is correct... I have a 1-2 collections for each user, and each of these collections has 1-2 indexes... and I have 10k+ users.

Comment: Well, something, somewhere, is doing the equivalent of 'db.streamified.system.indexes.find({ns:'cache_b7dd924a2dab81cc0d47346982d90ee1s'}).  The question is what, and why?  Is the query always for the same namespace, or does it vary?  What language are you using?  What driver version?  Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: Also: does the IP address "10.188.17.26" mean anything to you?